# PHP 7 array columns not working for multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-column

Below is my array structure:

```
Array
(
    [2016-09-01] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [hours_type_id] => 1
                    [date] => 2016-09-01
                    [hours] => 8.00
                    [ts_weekly_id] => 53428
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [hours_type_id] => 2
                    [date] => 2016-09-01
                    [hours] => 0.00
                    [ts_weekly_id] => 53428
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [hours_type_id] => 10
                    [date] => 2016-09-01
                    [hours] => 0.00
                    [ts_weekly_id] => 53428
                )

        )
```

I am trying to get all hours column in another array.

Below is the code:

```
$billcols   = array_column($billhours, "hours");
```

Is there any other function to get columns in array other than array_column which will work for multidimensional array like show above.

Comment: `$billcols   = array_column($billhours['2016-09-01'], "hours");` or loop.

Comment: that we can do easily, i mean what if there another date index in same array

Comment: This array is a range for date span say from one date to another date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra dimension, so:

```
$billcols = array_column($billhours['2016-09-01'], "hours");
```

If there are multiple dates, just loop and merge the results.  We don't use `$date` here, just an example:

```
$billcols = [];
foreach($billhours as $date => $array) {
    $billcols = array_merge($billcols, array_column($array, "hours"));
}
```

Comment: `$billcols = [];` and then `$billcols +=` ? :D